# Regex is accepting blank values

Tags: regex

I am making a regex for date format MM/DD/YYYY.

```
    String regex = "^(0[1-9]||1[0-2])/"
                + "([0-2][0-9]||3[0-1]||[1-9])/"
                + "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]||[0-9][0-9][0-9]||[0-9][0-9]||[0-9])$";
```

It works fine, but if I input // or 1/12/ it accepts the input.

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Your pattern, slightly modified, seems to be working](https://regex101.com/r/VEgVGd/1).

Comment: `a||b` means "match a OR match nothing OR match b". You probably intended `a|b`

Comment: jhnc was correct:  String regex = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])|[1-9]/"
     + "([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9])/"
     + "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])$";

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0[1-9])\/(\d{4})$` as your regex String. You messed up the day part a bit. I also also escaped the `/`. It should be working from year 0000 to 9999.

I would recommend trying to build up the expression in smaller bits (e.g. first "MM", then "DD", then "YYYY", then putting in the slashes) while using a regex tester (e.g. [this one](https://regex101.com/)).

Comment: @jhnc is right about `a||b`, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score -1):

This will work fine if you strictly follow MM/DD/YYYY

```
String regex = "^(0[1-9]{1}||1[0-2]{1}){1}/([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}||3[0-1]{1}||[1-9]{2}){1}/([0-9]{4}){1}$";
```

Comment: Did you actually test this pattern?

Comment: how about `//` or `1/12/` ?  :-)

Comment: `12/34/1970`, `/12/1970`, `//1970` are all invalid. By the way, appending `{1}` to anything seems a bit of a no-op.